# SQL Server spatial data accuracy question

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, geospatial, polygon, gis

Is there a possibility to save spatial data in SQL Server 2008 with an inches (or centimeters) accuracy? I would like to store a  `POLYGON` (square-shaped) that starts in a `40° 6' 48" N / 111° 51' 12" W` point and has a sides of 50 inches long.

I've found an example  of creating a `POLYGON` but couldn't find out what distances it represents.

```
INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeogCol1)
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText
('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658,
 -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326));
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with latitude/longitude points, distances vary with where you are on the globe.  You shouldn't have a problem with storing a polygon of any reasonable size as long as your points have sufficient precision.

If you have a closed polygon you can measure its length (perimeter) by using the `STLength()` command.  This should be in meters based on SRID 4326.